# Changing view modes in the view port

Tags: 3d-view

I've seen people doing this in many tutorials but non of them explained how to do it, clicking  <kbd>Z</kbd>  opens selectable buttons in the viewport around the cursor, something similar to Maya menus, I tried to click and hold  <kbd>Z</kbd>  but it kept toggling Solid and Wireframe, is this an add-on?  Anybody knows what's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an addon, it's called Pie Menus. You can activate it from user preferences -> addons